# UIImage to the Shapelayer in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

How can we fill a shape layer with image in iOS using swift 4 ? I have tried using below. I got an Black background. Here self is a Shapelayer where i am going to set an Image

```
 let image = UIImage(named: "ACVResources.bundle/temp.png")!
 let imageLayer = CALayer()
 imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "image")?.cgImage // Assign your image
 imageLayer.frame = self.frame
 imageLayer.mask = self
 self.masksToBounds = true
 self.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add CALayer(imageLayer) that fill your view after that you need to set that your view.layer mask your shapeLayer.
I give you an example:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500))
    customView.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(customView)

    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    let image = UIImage(named: "pxl.jpeg")
    imageLayer.contents = image?.cgImage
    imageLayer.frame = customView.frame
    customView.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: customView.frame.size.width / 2, y: 50))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: customView.frame.size.width, y: customView.frame.size.height / 2))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: customView.frame.size.height / 2))
    path.close()
    shape.path = path.cgPath

    customView.layer.mask = shape
```

[screenshot of that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BeOJ.png)

Comment: Here You have a CAlayer and Add image. For me I have a CAshapelayer. I need to add image to that CAShapelayer. Here you are adding a CAShapelayer to the view and Masking

Comment: I understand you but only option that maybe might work is setting image to compositingFilter property of you CAShapeLayer but it doesn't work so well